# How to change Android Spinner item's text size

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am accessing a spinner in java file, setting its input which is string array having US states name. I want to give my own size to selected state in spinner? How to give it custom size?

This is the Code:

```
Spinner state = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.state, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            state.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Xml:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/state"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:addStatesFromChildren="true" >
</Spinner>
```

String Array to Display in Spinner:

```
<string-array name="state">

        <item>Select State</item>
        <item>Alabama</item>
        <item>Alaska</item>
        <item>American Samoa</item>
        <item>Arizona</item>
        <item>Arkansas</item>
        <item>California</item>
        <item>Colorado</item>
        <item>Connecticut</item>
        <item>Delaware</item>
        <item>District of Columbia</item>
        <item>Florida</item>
        <item>Georgia</item>
        <item>Guam</item>
        <item>Hawaii</item>
        <item>Idaho</item>
        <item>Illinois</item>
        <item>Indiana</item>
        <item>Iowa</item>
        <item>Kansas</item>
        <item>Kentucky</item>
        <item>Louisiana</item>
        <item>Maine</item>
        <item>Maryland</item>
        <item>Massachusetts</item>
        <item>Michigan</item>
        <item>Minnesota</item>
        <item>Mississippi</item>
        <item>Missouri</item>
        <item>Montana</item>
        <item>Nebraska</item>
        <item>Nevada</item>
        <item>New Hampshire</item>
        <item>New Jersey</item>
        <item>New Mexico</item>
        <item>New York</item>
        <item>North Carolina</item>
        <item>North Dakota</item>
        <item>Northern Marianas Islands</item>
        <item>Ohio</item>
        <item>Oklahoma</item>
        <item>Oregon</item>
        <item>Pennsylvania</item>
        <item>Puerto Rico</item>
        <item>Rhode Island</item>
        <item>South Carolina</item>
        <item>South Dakota</item>
        <item>Tennessee</item>
        <item>Texas</item>
        <item>Utah</item>
        <item>Vermont</item>
        <item>Virginia</item>
        <item>Virgin Islands</item>
        <item>Washington</item>
        <item>West Virginia</item>
        <item>Wisconsin</item>
        <item>Wyoming</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

or you can give it your layout:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_layout);
```

and your my_layout.xml should look like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+android:id/text1" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a customized adapter like this,

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getParent()
                .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.my_spinner_style,spinner_values) {

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(18);

                return v;
            }

            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_drop_down);
                ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color
                        .parseColor(config.sort_by_label_color));
                return v;
            }
        };
```

**R.layout.my_spinner_style**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

And set this adapter to your spinner,

```
        spinner.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);
```